# Ubuntu Compatibility with Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, compatibility

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 on my PC, I have a Dell Vostro 230, core 2 duo 2.93 GHz, RAM 8Gb and an Nvidia GeForce GT220, but every time I try to run Ubuntu, after a few minutes the image is lost, I noticed that the cooler fan shuts down when Ubuntu starts, so I realize that the chip is heating too much. I already tried to install the Nvidia drivers without success. I can not install Ubuntu because it does not give me enough time. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Your hardware may not be powerful enough to run Ubuntu Desktop with GNOME. Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead

Comment: IMHO, the hardware is plenty powerful, and a legacy Nvidia driver should be available post installation. I don't know how to solve the fan problem though. May be there is a BIOS option, or an update.

Comment: Check the hardware first. Change thermal grease, remove all the dust from cooling system. Then install MATE or Lubuntu with Nvidia 340 driver.

Comment: I am using windows 10 on this PC, it works perfectly, I have also change the thermal grease, I know that's not a problem because the fan stops as soon as Ubuntu starts. Nothing to do with the thermal grease. I will try with Lubuntu now, thanks for your help, I will update the info soon.

Comment: Lubuntu/MATE/Xubuntu did not work. Just like Ubuntu, the fan stops as soon they start. Any other idea?